# Is it possible to simplify this expression where the only assumption made is that we have a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. $(X_i, Y_i)$ random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Is it possible to further simplify the following expression (you can assume that $p$ are probability densities)

\begin{align}
p(y_1, \dots, y_n \mid x_1, \dots, x_n)
&=
\frac{ p(y_1, \dots, y_n, x_1, \dots, x_n)}{p(x_1, \dots, x_n)}\\
&=
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i, x_i)}{p(x_1, \dots, x_n)} \\
&=
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i \mid x_i) p(x_i)}{p(x_1, \dots, x_n)}\\
&=
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i \mid x_i) \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)}{p(x_1, \dots, x_n)}
\end{align}

where the only assumption made is that we have a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. $(X_i, Y_i)$ random variables, so $p(x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i, y_i)$?

I have already tried different things, but I don't really know how to proceed. I think we can still change the denominator to $\int \dots \int p(x_1, \dots, x_n, \hat{y}_1, \dots, \hat{y}_n) d \hat{y}_1 \dots d \hat{y}_n$, right? But, even if that's right, then how do I proceed? The formula above should simplify to $\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i \mid x_i)$, but I don't really know how that can be done, unless we assume that $X_i$ is independent of $X_j$, for $i \neq j$. But how come that follow from the fact that the tuples $(X_i, Y_i)$ are i.i.d.. I don't see how that follows. Some sources, like [this one](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/node/111/), say that joint independence implies marginal independence, but I am not sure if this applies here and how to prove actually. I would need to prove that, if $p(a, b, c, d) = p(a, b)p(c, d)$, then $p(a, c) = p(a)p(c)$ (and I guess $p(a, d) = p(a)p(d)$, $p(b, c) = p(b)p(c)$ and $p(b, d) = p(b)p(d)$).

Comment: The $X_i$ are indeed independent of each other by: $$\begin{align*}P(X_i \in A, X_j \in B) &= P\left((X_i,Y_i) \in (A,\Bbb R), (X_j,Y_j) \in (B,\Bbb R)\right) \\ &=  P\left((X_i,Y_i) \in (A,\Bbb R)\right)\cdot P\left((X_j,Y_j) \in (B,\Bbb R)\right) \\ &= P(X_i \in A)\cdot P(X_j \in B)\end{align*}$$
In the same way you can show e.g. $X_1$ is independent of $(X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ so you get $$p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)$$

Comment: @Gono I don't understand your derivation. What's the meaning of $(X_i, Y_i) \in (A, \mathbb{R})$ and why is it equal to $X_i \in A$? Keep in mind that my knowledge of measure theory is like a small $\epsilon$.

Comment: $$(X_i,Y_i) \in (A,B) \quad\iff\quad X_i \in A\wedge Y_i \in B$$
So $$(X_i, Y_i) \in (A, \mathbb{R})$$ means $X_i \in A, Y_i \in \Bbb R$. Or in other words: $Y_i$ can be any number out of the reals, hence is arbitrary.

So we have obviously: $$X_i \in A \iff X_i \in A, Y_i \in \Bbb R$$

Comment: @Gono Well, I don't understand how $P((X_i, Y_i) \in (A, \mathbb{R}))$ turns into $P(X_i \in A)$, because $(X_i, Y_i) \in (A, \mathbb{R})$ is not equal to $X_i \in A$. The first condition $P((X_i, Y_i) \in (A, \mathbb{R}))$ is more restrictive than the second.

Comment: $$ P(X_i \in A, Y_i \in \mathbb R) = \int_A\int_\mathbb R p(x_i,y_i) dy_i dx_i = \int_A p(x_i) d x_i = P(X_i \in A) $$

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Ok, the second equality holds because of marginalization. But it's so weird that $p(x_i, y_i) = p(x_i)$. I still don't understand how this equation holds because you are basically saying that a joint is equal to the marginal but this is not generally true, even though I understand the marginalization part.

Comment: @nbro no it's not… you have $$\{X_i \in A \} = \{X_i \in A, Y_i \in \Bbb R\}$$ because $$\{Y_i \in \Bbb R\} = \Omega$$  

If you claim it's more restrictive: Please find an $\omega \in \Omega$ s.t. $$\omega \in \{X_i \in A\}$$ but $$\omega \not\in  \{X_i \in A, Y_i \in \Bbb R\}$$ 
All you need to do is to find a counter example. 

Good luck!

Comment: @Gono What if $Y_i \not \in \mathbb{R}$? You're intersecting the event $X_i \in A$ with the sample space, but why would you assume that $Y_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Then replace $\Bbb R$ by the space the $Y_i$ are mapped to… usually you deal with real valued random variables. But this doesn't change the proof at all. 
Btw. the comment of @TheoreticalEconomist also assume $Y_i$ is real valued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a different way to look at your denominator:

\begin{align*}
p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) &= \int_\mathbb R \cdots \int_\mathbb R p(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n)\,\mathrm dy_1\cdots \mathrm dy_n \\
&= \int_\mathbb R \cdots \int_\mathbb R \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i,y_i)\,\mathrm dy_1\cdots \mathrm dy_n \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n\int_\mathbb R p(x_i,y_i)\,\mathrm d y_i  \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i).
\end{align*}

$$  $$